# What is the difference between a Plugin and a Sensor

Tags: gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello all,

In http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.4/using_the_ros_plugins it says that "The imu sensor and the imu plugin are different because the ros plugin use a model plugin and not a sensor plugin."

What exactly is different between a plugin and a sensor? Can't we create camera plugin or camera sensor with the same behavior?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2679/what-is-the-difference-between-a-plugin-and-a-sensor/) by [peshala](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/111/peshala/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 197 on 2013-05-04

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

A sensor processes some aspect of simulation and outputs formatted data. For example, a camera sensor renders the scene and outputs an image.

There are many different kinds of plugins including:

```
1. Model: Controls a model
2. World: Controls the world 
3. System: Control load and unloading of the whole system
4. Sensor: Can be used to modify sensor behavior. This type of plugin can be used to add noise to a sensor stream, or make sensor output match a particular sensor model (such as a Hokuyo Laser)
```

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

A plugin is a piece of code that is used to problematically change things in a simulation. U have different kinds of plugins as said here :
http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.5/plugins/overview

A sensor is a device that can retrieve information from the simulated environment. U can write a sensor plugin in which you can do things with the sensor like retrive data from the sensor.

What I think they mean in the like u shared is that the sensor is not controller using a sensor plugin but rather a model plugin.

-Feel free to ask more

---

Originally posted by [Bharadwaj Ramesh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/154/bharadwaj-ramesh/) with karma: 51 on 2013-05-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PML](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1147/pml/) on 2015-06-18**:
I think you meant programmatically not problematically, lol.